# Make friendly URL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, friendly-url, seo

how do i make my web app friendly URL?

currently my app URL looks like this

http://www.domain.com/Page.aspx?article=103

but I would like to display the URL to look like this

http://www.domain.com/Page.aspx?Google-likes-url-friendly

what would i need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

you will need to download and install a module.

Pretty easy to use and configure.

Here is the introduction :

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 2):

Look into using ASP.NET MVC. With it, you could have a URL that's even better: http://www.domain.com/Article/Google-likes-url-friendly

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET 3.5SP1 or later you can use ASP.NET routing even with ASP.NET forms, not just MVC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ASP.NET 4.0 or .NET 3.5 SP1 (or ASP.NET MVC), you can use the routing module.

[ASP.NET Routing @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

There is a good walkthrough at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the url-rewrite module metioned above only works with IIS7/7.5.  And make sure your host, if you are using one, has it installed.

For IIS6, IIS5, take a look here:

[Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

ASP.NET routing and URL rewriting will both work.  Here are the differences:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write a 404 trap: http://codeeleven.blogspot.com/2007/11/rewriting-urls-in-aspnet-without-using.html

Hacky, but an effective last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls Nuget Package to Make this easy