# How to get user friendly URLs without any file extensions?

Tags: html, url, web, webserver

I've been wondering for a long time how people manage to get their URLs to work without file extentions such as '.html' or '.apsx' on the end.

Look at this website for example:

```
http://www.axongarside.com/Communication
http://www.axongarside.com/Communication/Compleat
http://www.axongarside.com/Brand
http://www.axongarside.com/Brand/K3-Group
```

How have they accomplished this? The only method I can think of would be to create a new directory for each page and have an index page in each directory but this would be a huge hassle for a larger website. Is there any other way?

Thankyou

Comment: Url rewriting, ASP.NET Routing etc. What kind of software are you using for your webserver, application etc?

Comment: URL Rewriting - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: Using the URL Rewrite Module, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039166/make-friendly-url-in-asp-net

Comment: This is called URL rewriting. It is a process in which you configure your server to fire a, for example, `product.aspx` file when the URL matches a certain pattern, for example, `http://example.com/products/<slug>`. And the directory/page does not have to exist physically.

Comment: Thanks guys! You've been a real help

Comment: Also you can use a hashtag that will redirect from `example.com#page` -> `example.com/page.html`. check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66357780/10382407

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three most common ways are to:

- Use index pages (i.e. just create a directory and put an `index.html` file in it).
- Use a rewrite engine (such as Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/)) to map the URLs onto different files (this is a common approach in PHP-land).
- Use a front controller script which processes the URLs for you (this is the usual approach for MVC frameworks).

The latter approach would use something like this in an Apache server configuration:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup example
WSGIScriptAlias / /hosts/example.com/application/wsgi.py
```

or

```
SetHandler fcgid-script
Alias / /hosts/example/application.fcgi/
```

For scripts using WSGI (Python) or FastCGI (Cross-language, that particular example was cribbed from a Perl application I'm writing) respectively.

The URL format would be handled by the script itself, and different frameworks take different approaches to the problem.

In Catalyst, this is done by [providing attributes to subroutine names](http://search.cpan.org/~hkclark/Catalyst-Manual-5.9006/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Action_types).

Dancer has its own [route handler syntax](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer::Tutorial#Our-first-route-handler).

Web::Simple uses [subroutine prototypes](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Web-Simple/lib/Web/Simple.pm#Web::Simple_match_specifications).

Django uses [a separate file containing a list of patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache you can use the .htaccess file to remove the .html extension like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

To remove the .html extension from the url just link to the page without .html

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page">linkhere</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache HTTP Server you should check [mod_rewrite](https://www.google.com/search?q=modrewrite&oq=modrewrite&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=mod%20rewrite%20user%20friendly%20urls&oq=mod_rewrite%20user%20friendl&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i30l2.7976.11287.0.12234.15.14.1.0.0.0.106.1364.10j4.14.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.a2m6-zyyaC4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.ZG4&fp=2246e513cc5097bd&biw=1280&bih=920)  capability. 
IIS also has a similar URL rewrite feature.